# Spark performance improvement for self join with TBs of data

Tags: sql, performance, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

First, a bit of context :
I have the following dataframe

| person_id | zone |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| B | X |
| B | Y |
| C | X |
| C | Z |

And I would like to know, for each zone, how many IDs in common we saw with every other zone, thus I perform a self join on this dataframe like this :

```
    val res = data
       .join(data.withColumnRenamed("zone", "other_zone"), Seq("person_id"))
       .where($"zone" =!= $"other_zone")
```

| person_id | zone | other_zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | Y |
| A | Y | X |
| B | X | Y |
| B | Y | X |
| C | X | Z |
| C | Z | X |

And then I group by / count like this :

```
val intersection = res.groupBy("zone", "other_zone").count
```

| zone | other_zone | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | 2 |
| Y | X | 2 |
| X | Z | 1 |
| Z | X | 1 |

This is the result I want.

Problem is, my dataframe (from the beginning) has **10 billion rows**. Performing the self-join is very time consuming so I'd like to find another way to compute this final dataframe.

I tried to replace the join by a mapPartition instead since I have all I need in this single dataframe but I have to repartition by person_id beforehand to make sure all zones for the same id are in the same partition.
It's working fine on a toy dataset (~ millions of rows) but it totally gets stuck for the real one.

Any help appreciated ! Thanks

*Below is a small code example*

```
val data = Seq(
  ("A", "X"),
  ("A", "Y"),
  ("B", "X"),
  ("B", "Y"),
  ("C", "X"),
  ("C", "Z")
).toDF("person_id", "zone")


val res = data
  .join(data.withColumnRenamed("zone", "other_zone"), Seq("person_id"))
  .where($"zone" =!= $"other_zone")

val intersection = res.groupBy("zone", "other_zone").count

intersection.show
```

Comment: Why not run a `groupBy("person_id")` and then build a list of tuple, then `explode` and run a `count` over the tuple exploded? It would avoid having to shuffle the dataset twice with the self join

Comment: How many different values do you have in "zone" column ? And in "person_id" column ? you can obtain those information using `data.select(countDistinct("zone"), countDistinct("person_id"))`

Comment: @Quentin thank you it helped my job take 25% less time than my previous code

Comment: @VincentDoba person_id should be more than 50M and zone should be ~ 15M